static routing settings on Keentic GIGA
please help me figure out the static routing on the Keenetic GIGA router.
There are two different networks, the diagram in the screenshot

network No. 1 192.168.1.0 (local IP address of the router 192.168.1.1)
network No. 2 10.1.1.0 (local IP address of the router 10.1.1.1)

now to access the local site located on the network 10.1.1.0 I have to register the ip address settings and a static route on each computer in the organization

I do it like this
PC Win 10 settings interface "Ethernet"
netsh interface ip set address      "Ethernet"  static      192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
netsh interface ipv4 add dns        "Ethernet"              8.8.8.8
netsh interface ipv4 add address    "Ethernet"              10.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
route -p add 10.1.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.1

That is, there are two IP addresses on each computer, one is 192.168.1.2, the second is 10.1.1.2 and a static route is specified for the second address, which says that all accesses to the 10.1.1.0 network should be sent through the 10.1.1.1 gateway
Obviously, this path is extremely inefficient, please tell me how to make such settings on the Keenetic GIGA router so that it redirects all requests to the 10.1.1.0 network on its own. So that I can enable DHCP on the router and forget about manually maintaining IP address tables.
